# Brace and de-centered array with [t]

Tags: arrays, braces

I did not find an answer to my problem, which is quite easy : I want to put a brace on the left of an array that I had "de-centered" with the option [t] (see the following code). The thing is that the brace goes up without reason that I can understand. Can anybody help me ? Thanks

```
\left\{ \begin{array}[t]{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right.
```

Comment: If you find it not so beautiful now, how would you like it to look?

Answer (score 3):

the brace is always centred on the math axis, so if the array has large depth, then the brace has large height to match.

The `delarray` package was written for precisely this issue,

```
\usepackage{delarray}
```

then

```
\begin{array}[t]\{{cc}. a & b \\ c & d \end{array}
```